# Weld ContextNotActiveException in async servlet

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly, weld

Environment:

1. WildFly 9.0.1/9.0.2
2. Java EE 7 Full profile
3. Weld CDI environment.

Because of the number of requests I am expecting, I want to implement async request on top of the FacesServlet, and did this:

```
public class AsyncFacesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 111966573758921845L;

    private FacesServlet delegate;

    @Inject
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    @Inject
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void init(final ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        delegate = new FacesServlet();
        delegate.init(servletConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        delegate.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return delegate.getServletConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return delegate.getServletInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void service(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.isAsyncStarted()
                ? request.getAsyncContext() : request.startAsync(request, response);
        final Runnable runnable = () -> {

            try {
                delegate.service(request, response);
            } catch (final IOException | ServletException ex) {
                throw Throwables.propagate(ex);
            }
        };

        asyncContext.start(runnable);
    }
}
```

And then updated my web.xml as:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.service.faces.AsyncFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

When I deploy, I get the following exceptions, which indicates that Weld was not correctly initialized inside the asynccontext.

```
SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-38) Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:178)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:761)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at com.mycompany.service.faces.servlet.AsyncFacesServlet.lambda$service$17(AsyncFacesServlet.java:61)
```

Whats happening is that, Weld is not properly initialized or context is not propagated to the async context execution.

How can I be able to propagate or recreate the weld context upon async-request call?

Comment: So where is your context file? In META-INF/context.xml?

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik what context file? CDI uses beans.xml, and i am running under wildfly not tomcat/jetty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll prefix my answer with a note that there is an open CDI spec issue to make async behavior more portable, [Specify that web scoped (request, session, application) beans are injectable in async servlets](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-452)

What you can do, in a Weld specific way, is start the context.  Apache DeltaSpike has some utilities that will make this container in-specific as well, http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/container-control.html#ContextControlUsage

If your runnable is a managed bean, you can use `BoundRequestContext` in weld to start a request context for that thread.  [More here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/contexts.html).  The downside is that its a new context, not a bridged context.